# Filter results in a single string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given two tables like those above. The first one contains the data that should be filtered as a single string in the second one.

| 1st table | A | B | C | D | E | ... | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1st row | Tese | 1 | Tema | 3 | Vinculo | ... | 221 |
| 2nd row | Tese | 2 | Tema | 5 | Sem | ... | 443 |
| 3rd row | Tese | 5 | Tema | 9 | Vínculo | ... | 221 |
| 4th row | Tese | 7 |  |  | Vinculo | ... | 221 |

| 2nd table | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1st row | 221 | Tese 1>Tema 3>Vínculo>Tese 5>Tema 9>Vinculo>Tese 7>Vinculo |
| 2nd row | 443 | Tese 2>Tema 5>Sem |

Also, as the table is huge, I need an array formula or a query...

Is there hope for me?

Link to the actual table [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A05Wy2GOiY3Z-Bouis_hBWUTxBQdRe4ir5HFdJsVLCA/edit#gid=1357173481)

Comment: Do the dots mean the pattern continues of names and numbers up until column M? and that those columns are also supposed to be included?

Comment: No, the dots means those columns are irrelevant. I just need the five first columns data in the results

Comment: "data that should be filtered as a single string" .. d u mean "combine as a single string" ?

Comment: yes! the outcome must be in a single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possible to do it all in one Arrayformula, but I would not recommend it and do not have the ability to answer follow up questions.  [See this sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZGvYS2aRDAbxwuxxr3q-hIXofxky-DJ-5_tXpxGv1k/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(MID(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN("00000_"&Data!M2:M&"#|"&TEXT(ROW(Data!A2:A)*10+{1,2,3},"00000")&"_>"&{Data!A2:A&" "&Data!B2:B,Data!C2:C&" "&Data!D2:D,Data!E2:E}),"|",0,0),"select MAX(Col2) where not Col2 ends with ' ' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),7,1000),,9^9))),"# >",0),"offset 1",0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple query statements for each unique value in column M:

So in the first column (assuming this is a different sheet) use:

```
=UNIQUE(Sheet1!M1:M)
```

Then on the second column use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(">",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(QUERY(Sheet1!$A$1:$M,"select A,B,C,D,E where M = "&$A1))))
```

Since `ARRAYFORMULA` does not support multiple query statements on different conditions, you need to drag down or use autofill.

**Sample:**

[image]